# Add underscore between each character of a string

Tags: string, python-2.7

I am currently looking for a way in which I can add a underscore 
in a string generated as such:

```
>>> bin(1)[2:].zfill(8)
'00000001'
```

I want the string to be `'0_0_0_0_0_0_0_1'`

How do i add the underscore between each character?

Comment: What about `'_'.join(txt)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved in multiple ways and has already been answered a lot of times here. Usually people seem to do to some kind of replace operation but there are other ways. Here's how to use the String join() method.

```
s = "00000001"
"_".join(s)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help though :)